# Will using NSRequiresCertificateTransparency have unintended behaviour?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am implementing certificate transparency using ATS settings for my custom domains. The official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsrequirescertificatetransparency), gives a warning like this,

> "Don’t use this key. The current system enforces this behavior, and
> new certificates can’t meet the requirement on older systems."

I couldn't find any other documentation or release notes that explains this warning. My app supports 12.0 and above and I am not sure if adding this key will break my application in Prod.

Is there any release note or doc that explains this warning so I can implement CT safely in my applications.